# How can I increase one of two numbers in a comparative statement with a button click

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm making a little UWP app in C# that simulates drawing straws. The problem that I'm having is that I want the user to get to a point where they click a button, and the variable baseNumber (initially set to 2 -- the fewest amount of drawn straws to make any sense) is compared to a randomly generated number that is passed through from another button event. I have this part down.

The part that is giving me fits is that I want the next user to then click the same button, and I want the baseNumber incremented by 1, and have that new number compared to the losingStraw. If that user is declared safe, I want the number to increment again for the next user with their button click, until ultimately the numbers equal each other, a user draws the short straw, and another code path is taken.

I'm very new to coding, so what I want might not even be possible. Here's an example of what I've tried, below. I have also tried variants on a do / do while and a for loop.

If I could somehow stop something like a for loop at each pass and make it wait for user input (the button press), that would be ideal. I couldn't figure that out either though.

Any help or ideas you can offer would be greatly appreciated!

```
private void drawButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  
        {

            int baseNumber = 2;
            int losingStraw = Convert.ToInt32(drawButton.Tag);   

            if (baseNumber < losingStraw)
            {
                instructions.Text = "You are safe!";
                baseNumber = baseNumber++; // that doesn't work at all. I was hoping that baseNumber
            }
            else
            {
                instructions.Text = "You have drawn the losing straw";
            }

        }
```

Comment: instead of `baseNumber = baseNumber++;` just make `baseNumber++;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write `baseNumber++;` instead of `baseNumber = baseNumber++;` since `++` aka the unary operators helps increases integer value by one. Thus `baseNumber++;` means `baseNumber = baseNumber + 1;`

Edit

In your case the variable `int baseNumber = 2;` has been declare and initialized in the event itself thus every-time the event is fired the `baseNumber` will be initialized by 2 and you would not be able to see any changes. Thus you can do something like this

```
int baseNumber; // you can do 2 here as well
public YourFormName() 
{
    baseNumber = 2; 
}  

private void drawButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  
{
    int losingStraw = Convert.ToInt32(drawButton.Tag);   
    if (baseNumber < losingStraw)
    {
        instructions.Text = "You are safe!";
        baseNumber = baseNumber++; // that doesn't work at all. I was hoping that baseNumber
    }
    else
    {
        instructions.Text = "You have drawn the losing straw";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Mohit, but that doesn't actually fix the issue. 

baseNumber++ does indeed increase baseNumber by 1, but it doesn't affect the variable outside my if statement so that the next pass through increments the number in the comparison. I presume it has something to do with variable scope... but I'm not sure.

Comment: You are absolutely correct @MatthewKelley. It has to do with Variable scope. Lemme update the answer.

Comment: That was it Mohit!  Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

Just put the baseNumber outside the method, can be globally declared so that everytime you increment it, it will never to reset to 2 again when entered on butotn click :) **-HAPPY CODING-**

```
public class YourClass
{
    int baseNumber = 2;

    private void drawButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  
    {
        int losingStraw = Convert.ToInt32(drawButton.Tag);   

        if (baseNumber < losingStraw)
        {
            instructions.Text = "You are safe!";
            baseNumber = baseNumber++; // that doesn't work at all. I was hoping that baseNumber
        }
        else
        {
            instructions.Text = "You have drawn the losing straw";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: No problem :) I hope it helps you alot !